# jQuery insert new input box on keyup dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, insert, keyup

Here is the original post:
[Multiple dynamic input text javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913051/multiple-dynamic-input-text-javascript)

`Here is my attempt:`
http://jsfiddle.net/AZz6R/

I found that the difference between my attempt and the original post might possibly be how JavaScript and jQuery treat the return statement. In the original post, the code will still execute after the return statement for some reason.

My question is can anyone help me to make the code work in jQuery instead of plain JavaScript?

Comment: Try remove return from this row: else if($(this).next().val.length > 0) {
        console.log('here');
        //return;
    }

Comment: I tried that before I post the question. It will clone a new input every time I press a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#myDiv').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).next().remove();
        return;
    }
    else if($(this).next().val() == '') {
        console.log('here');
        return;
    }

    var newTxt = $(this).clone();
    var id = newTxt.attr('id');
    newTxt.attr('id', 'txt_' + (parseInt(id.substring(id.indexOf('_') + 1))));
    newTxt.val('');
    $(this).parent().append(newTxt);

});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CYsv/2/)**

Comment: It is working, but it won't clone a new input unless there are two or more chars. Same to removing the empty input, I need to hit backspace twice to remove the empty input. I want the input to clone as soon as there is one char in the box and remove the next input as soon as current input has nothing in the box. Can you please see what's wrong with it? Thank you! @bksi

Comment: See my edited answer. You used keydown event, so it will fire at next keydown. This is the reason to start after second char. Now it works after first char keyup.

Answer (score 0):

main issue in your code is the `if` conditions. change it as follows should work:

```
if($(this).val()==''){
    $(this).next().remove();
    return;
}
else if($(this).next().val()) {
    console.log('here');
    return;
}
```

Second issue is, value is not getting empty for cloned input. change it as below will work:

```
newTxt.val('');
```